# How to add new place/location to facebook places with API of iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

We are developing iPhone application for nature lovers. We want to add feature to report new place or location if it does not exists in facebook places.

Is there any way to add places with facebook API?

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: This is not possible via the API currently.